# New to Z3 - Some little guidance is needed

Tags: z3

I am new to Z3 and haven't exposed to it before.

I am so interested in this filed and my research work requires me to be familiar with Z3.

unfortunately I am facing some issues as I need a little push/guidance at the beginning from an experts.

I am a quick learner and eager to get the info
Please let me know if by any chance you think you can give a little guidance/help that would be great.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Start with [https://theory.stanford.edu/~nikolaj/programmingz3.html](https://theory.stanford.edu/%7Enikolaj/programmingz3.html)

Stack-overflow is much more suitable for specific programming questions, as opposed to general advice. However, reading through the above document will get you started in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, is there a community to join like an online z3 community to study with and to ask

Comment: None that I know of. However, if you have specific questions, stack-overflow is the perfect place to ask. Start by browsing existing questions and reading through them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/z3+z3py